# Why is "1" being stored in all array index positions?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, printf

I'm learning and practicing C. Output formatting aside. I don't understand why "1" is being output for all array elements, or where the number is even coming from.

Even if I input 5 "5"s, the output is still always "1".

```
#define LIMIT 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void getNums();

int main() {
    getNums();
    return 0;
}

void getNums() {
    int newRay[LIMIT];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int element;
        int result = scanf("%d", &element); 
        newRay[i] = result;
        printf("%d", newRay[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` stores the return value of `scanf`, that is, the **number of matches** in the format string supplied to `scanf`. What you really want is **the value read**, stored in `element`:

```
        newRay[i] = element;
```

---

Notes:

- better use `LIMIT` consistently. Your program might just be "quick'n'dirty" but you should replace the`5` in the `for`-loop anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` returns the number of successfully assigned inputs. In your case, if the assignment to `element` is successful, it return 1.

You probably meant to use:

```
    newRay[i] = element;
```

What you should do is:

```
    int result = scanf("%d", &element);
    if ( result == 1 )
    {
       newRay[i] = element;
    }
    else
    {
       // Unable to read the input
       // Deal with error.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning return value of `scanf` to array elements. `scanf` returns the number of input items assigned.

In `scanf("%d", &element);`, there is only one input item assigned, so it will return `1`.

Change

```
int result = scanf("%d", &element); 
newRay[i] = result;
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &element);
newRay[i] =  element
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting "1" as result is because you only catch the returning value of scanf function. The value you entered is returned by scanf but instead it is copied to element (which you used by referencing it - &element). NO need for the result variable.

`void getNums(){
    int newRay[LIMIT];
    int element;
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
       scanf("%d",&element);
       newRay[i] = element;
       printf("%d", newRay[i]); 
    }
}`